# Issue when Manually copy/paste date format from one Excel wroksheet to one other

Tags: excel

When I try to manually copy and paste dates from one excel workbook to another, the pasted date doesn't match the copied one.

In workbook 1, let's say I have 01/02/17, in workbook 2 I get 31/01/13. The format is however the same.

(But if I paste the date in sheet 2 of workbook 1, it stays the same)

Would you have some clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `1904` dates. Change it to normal ones and it would be fixed.

See [**Problems Linking and Copying Dates Between Workbooks**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel) and follow the steps:

To set the date system for a workbook in Microsoft Office Excel 2007, follow these steps:

- Open or switch to the workbook.
- Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options.
- Click Advanced.
- Click to unselect the Use 1904 data system check box under the When calculating this workbook, and then click OK.

I was experiencing the same problem in VBA some year ago:
[VBA - copying dates from one cell to another - strange change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789271/vba-copying-dates-from-one-cell-to-another-strange-change)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I really didn't know about that !